# Scrape JS generated Data with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, scrape

I have created a script using PHP do get Data of a site. This works great for the data displayed by PHP or HTML but I would like to pick up data using JavaScript. The file_get_html does not return the Data but the Javascript function. 
Is there a simple way of doing this? Im not too familiar with most other languages.
Thank you.

Comment: i think you are going to have to use something like phantomjs to get the resulting markup from a script run and then pass that into php for analysis

Comment: you can easily write a tampermonkey script to rip the generated content. that script can be controlled from php using an injected script tag that php spits out. once ripped, you can ajax or submit() the data back to your php.